# Loop scanf problem, crashes after several tries

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, scanf

So im trying to make a program that inputs grade using arrays, this is the main loop. The problem is that it successfully asks the input but after the 5th student, 1st subject, it crashes,  where did I go wrong???

crash starts when studloop=4; gradloop=2

```
float data[4][7];
for(studLoop = 0; studLoop < 5; studLoop++){

    ave=0;
    printf("\nStudent %d ID#", studLoop+1);
    data[studLoop][0] = inputNum();
    for(gradLoop = 1; gradLoop < 7; gradLoop++){

        printf("Subject %d: ", gradLoop);
        data[studLoop][gradLoop] = inputNum();
        gradLoop = checkGrade(data[studLoop][gradLoop], gradLoop, ave);

    }
    data[studLoop][7] = ave / 6;
    printf("press any key to continue...");
    getch();
    system("cls");
}
```

Comment: `studLoop < 5;` should be `studLoop < 4;` because the array `float data[4][7];` allows only 4 students. You also probably want `gradLoop = 0;` not `gradLoop = 1;` Moreover `data[studLoop][7]` is also breaking the array bounds.

Comment: the student number is given 5, so i dont have to change it anymore. If i change it to 4, it wont ask for the grades of student 5

Comment: okay so our task was a 2d array problem

Comment: There isn't room for student 5, only 4 students. If you want 5 students you need `float data[5][7];`

Comment: imagine the grid analogy, 
the first column(data[0][])would contain the student ID numbers
the second to sixth column  would contain the grades of the students (data[][1-6])
the last column(data[][7]) would contain the average of the grades

Comment: holy crud it workes

Comment: I changed it to data[5][7] and

Comment: In that case the array would be `float data[STUDENTS][SUBJECTS+2];` Please don't hard-code "magic numbers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since you're trying to store 5 students and 7 grades for each, then this:

```
float data[4][7];
```

should be

```
float data[5][7];
```

Comment: why does this work??

if counting starts at 0, then it [4] would be enough right? 
0-4 = 5 values?? sorry beginner

Comment: @GermanIIIFelisarta The syntax `float data[4]` creates an array with room for 4 elements, with indices from `0-3`. It does not mean the highest index for the array is 4.

Comment: It works because by doing that you're declaring the size and not the index @GermanIIIFelisarta , You only use 0 to 4 to access the indexes

Answer (score 0):

C uses [0-based array indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering), so for an array defined like

```
float data[4][7];
```

the loop condition

```
 for(studLoop = 0; studLoop < 5; studLoop++)
```

is [off by one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). It should be

```
 for(studLoop = 0; studLoop < 4; studLoop++)
```

The same is applicable for `for(gradLoop = 1; gradLoop < 7; gradLoop++)` also, where the initial index value should start with `0`.

---

*Revision after the comment:*

According to the requirement, 7 grades for 5 students, the array should be **defined** like

```
float data[5][7];
             ^^^------------------------------ number of grades
          ^^^--------------------------------- number of students
```

Then, for the usage, the valid index for students would be `data[0]` to `data[4]` and for each of the students, the grade holders will run from `data[i][0]` to `data[i][6]`, where `0<i<5`.